# How do I navigate to external drives using the file browser?

Tags: file-browser

How to navigate to external drives using this blender nav system?

For example, if I'm in the "C" directory, how do I use use the navigation buttons to go to the desktop or external hard drives without typing it in?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's in the left panel.

- *View > Source List*
- Shortcut: <kbd>T</kbd>

Or just drag that little arrow on the left...

[image]